# Doom Emacs Custom ASCII Splash SCreen - Left indent is too great

Tags: emacs, ascii

For the record, I'm just gettin' my feet wet with Emacs, Doom, and I've never written a line of Lisp before (I'm assuming this code is Lisp?). This is a good ol' learning moment for me, so feel free to spare me no detail in the response (or just solve my problems, totally fine either way).

I snagged this script from the interweb, it 'almost' works perfect. There's a big ol' indent on the lefthand side that's pushing my ASCII too far to the right. What's causing that to happen, and how can I get it nice and centered?

**Image 1**: [Screenshot: config.el custom function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtXPZ.png)

**Image 2**: [Indented ASCII splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unGs5.png)

Code below, sorry for the mess. It's also in the screenshot.

```
    (defun custom_banner ()
  (let* (
         (banner
          '(
"        ▄████████  ▄████████    ▄████████    ▄████████         ▄████████    ▄███████▄    ▄████████ ████████▄     ▄████████    ▄████████            "
"        ███    ███ ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███        ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███ ███   ▀███   ███    ███   ███    ███           "
"        ███    ███ ███    █▀    ███    █▀    ███    ███        ███    █▀    ███    ███   ███    ███ ███    ███   ███    █▀    ███    █▀            "
"        ███    ███ ███         ▄███▄▄▄       ███    ███        ███          ███    ███   ███    ███ ███    ███  ▄███▄▄▄       ███                  "
"      ▀███████████ ███        ▀▀███▀▀▀     ▀███████████      ▀███████████ ▀█████████▀  ▀███████████ ███    ███ ▀▀███▀▀▀     ▀███████████           "
"        ███    ███ ███    █▄    ███    █▄    ███    ███               ███   ███          ███    ███ ███    ███   ███    █▄           ███           "
"        ███    ███ ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███         ▄█    ███   ███          ███    ███ ███   ▄███   ███    ███    ▄█    ███           "
"        ███    █▀  ████████▀    ██████████   ███    █▀        ▄████████▀   ▄████▀        ███    █▀  ████████▀    ██████████  ▄████████▀            "
"                                                                                                                                                   "
"   ▄████████   ▄▄▄▄███▄▄▄▄   ███    █▄  ███▄▄▄▄           ▄█   ▄█▄    ▄█    █▄       ▄████████    ▄███████▄    ▄████████    ▄████████    ▄████████ "
"  ███    ███ ▄██▀▀▀███▀▀▀██▄ ███    ███ ███▀▀▀██▄        ███ ▄███▀   ███    ███     ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███ "
"  ███    ███ ███   ███   ███ ███    ███ ███   ███        ███▐██▀     ███    ███     ███    █▀    ███    ███   ███    █▀    ███    ███   ███    ███ "
"  ███    ███ ███   ███   ███ ███    ███ ███   ███       ▄█████▀     ▄███▄▄▄▄███▄▄  ▄███▄▄▄       ███    ███  ▄███▄▄▄      ▄███▄▄▄▄██▀   ███    ███ "
"▀███████████ ███   ███   ███ ███    ███ ███   ███      ▀▀█████▄    ▀▀███▀▀▀▀███▀  ▀▀███▀▀▀     ▀█████████▀  ▀▀███▀▀▀     ▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀   ▀███████████ "
"  ███    ███ ███   ███   ███ ███    ███ ███   ███        ███▐██▄     ███    ███     ███    █▄    ███          ███    █▄  ▀███████████   ███    ███ "
"  ███    ███ ███   ███   ███ ███    ███ ███   ███        ███ ▀███▄   ███    ███     ███    ███   ███          ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███ "
"  ███    █▀   ▀█   ███   █▀  ████████▀   ▀█   █▀         ███   ▀█▀   ███    █▀      ██████████  ▄████▀        ██████████   ███    ███   ███    █▀  "
"                                                         ▀                                                                 ███    ███              "))
        (longest-line (apply #'max (mapcar #'length banner))))
    (put-text-property
     (point)
     (dolist (line banner (point))
       (insert (+doom-dashboard--center
                +doom-dashboard--width
                (concat line (make-string (max 0 (- longest-line (length line))) 32)))
               "\n"))
     'face 'doom-dashboard-banner))
  )

(setq +doom-dashboard-ascii-banner-fn #'custom_banner)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like someone's fist lisp program, so I'm assuming you copied this from somewhere. Where did it come from? That context would be useful: perhaps that place contains further instructions or context about what else you need to do. `+doom-dashboard--center` looks relevant, at least.

Comment: @amalloy You'll find it here: https://discourse.doomemacs.org/t/how-to-change-your-splash-screen/57

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, that function is not designed to work with banners as wide as yours. Note yours is a lot wider than the default and the examples given at the site you link in the comments.

Observe that `+doom-dashboard--width` is [defined as 80](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/e0385052a8004ec54a402c27357b1352840eb798/modules/ui/doom-dashboard/config.el#L96), suggesting to me that you're not supposed to use a splash screen any wider than that. You could try just removing the call to `+doom-dashboard--width` and all the other centering logic, since your text is already pre-centered. Maybe it works, but no guarantees.

```
...
     (dolist (line banner (point))
       (insert line "\n"))
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @amalloy. I gave that a shot, but the lefthand indent (slightly brighter than the rest of the screen) persists, same as the screenshot I included in original post.